# Xcode Archive Validation Error: "No suitable application records were found."

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7, code-signing

I am currently having issues validating and uploading my Xcode to itunesconnect. I have done it plenty of times before with other build numbers and now all of a sudden it will not work. I am using an opensource framework called SCLAlertView. Uploading my project with that framework in the past was fine but now it will not work. I have searched through just about every related thread from google and could not find a solution. The exact error is "Archive validation operation failed due to the issues listed below. iTunes Store operation failed. No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'org.cocoapods.SCLAlertView' is correct." I tried messing with the code signing identifier and provisional profile settings but nothing seems to be working. Also I would like to emphasize that the error is only given for the SCLAlertView framework, not my main application. I would appreciate any advice on how to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.